# How to integrate PDFBox.jar into Android Project?

Tags: java, android, jar, pdfbox

I am aware that this question has been asked several times however I can not solve my problem. I am using pdfbox-1.8.7.jar. My intention is to read the content of a `PDF` document and output it in the console.

I put the pdfbox-1.8.7.jar into the libs folder. *app/libs/pdfbox-1.8.7.jar*. 
I am able to import the content of the jar, into my class.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
```

But if I run the application, an exception occurs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
```

Comment: Does no body wants to help me :((

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Android Forked version of PDF Box

https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android

It has the Gradle Build which will work on Android Studio